# Excel windows invisible when laptop comes back from sleep

Tags: laptop, hibernate, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013 via Office 365 and it's the damndest thing but when I put my laptop to sleep and it goes into hibernation when I resume windows all of my excel windows are invisible.  They show up in my taskbar, I can 'maximize' them, my cursor changes as I go over cells, I can press alt and bring up all those shortcut letters at the top, but the window is completely invisible.   Meaning I can see whatever is behind it, thunderbird for example, but I can't click on it because the invisible excel window steals my mouse clicks.

I can open a new excel window and it shows up just fine, I can close the invisible ones down and they save dialogue box comes up just fine, but outside of that I can't do anything to bring it back.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could be a problem with graphics drivers or hardware compatibility. You could also try disabling Aero if it's enabled.

Comment: Try moving it to your screen with <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> (or any other arrow key!

Answer (score 0):

Silly of me not to try this but if you go into the task bar, click on the excel window to bring up all of your open sheets and then right click->restore for each of them they will become visible again

Answer (score 0):

This also happens with Word, Outlook and presumably other Office apps.  Although Restore was initially unavailable, I first chose Minimize - even with my Outlook Reminders.  Then a right-click > Restore worked in each invisible window.

Note to superuser.com webmaster - would be nice if we could add a semicolon or comma and then a second email address for responses to our posts.

Comment: There is a dedicated site for posts about the operation of the site: http://meta.superuser.com/.  That would be the place for your second paragraph.  You would want to clarify the location you're referring to (profile page?).

Answer (score -1):

If you minimise all of your office windows before going to sleep / hibernate, upon restore you can bring all your windows back up ok.

If you forgot to minimise before going to sleep / hibernate, look in your invisible window and find the minimise button and click. Then bring it back up from the taskbar and all is good.

It's a pain in the proverbial, but how long before Microsoft will fix this? All other programs work fine after coming out of sleep / hibernate.

Answer (score -1):

This happens on my desktop PC with Excel 2013 on Win7 32 bit. It's annoying, but I bring the windows back by grabbing the invisible title bar and dragging down to un-maximize the window and then pushing it back up to re-maximize it. I do this for each one that has gone transparent. Maybe MS is working on a solution?